# What is the precision (in decimal points) of python floats?

Tags: python, floating-point

I am trying to determine how precise python floats are when comparing to zero. Observe the following:

```
1e-323 == 0
> False
1e-324 == 0
> True
```

I appears the threshold is 324 decimal points, at least with the implementation I am running (python 2.7, CPython). Is this documented anywhere? Is it implementation dependent?

Comment: I don't think you can trust that threshold to always hold, even limited to your own environment. For instance, consider that `1e100 == 1e100 + 1`. This implies that especially large floats don't have even a single digit of precision after the decimal point.

Comment: math.isclose() may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024979/3841261

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is [implementation-specific](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#numbers-real-float):

> [`numbers.Real`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real) ([`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float))
>
> These represent machine-level double
> precision floating point numbers. You are at the mercy of the
> underlying machine architecture (and C or Java implementation) for the
> accepted range and handling of overflow. Python does not support
> single-precision floating point numbers; the savings in processor and
> memory usage that are usually the reason for using these are dwarfed
> by the overhead of using objects in Python, so there is no reason to
> complicate the language with two kinds of floating point numbers.

You can, however, [query this information at run time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

```
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

Comment: Look at the docs for `sys.float_info`.  That exposes various info about the specific implementation.  However, on almost all platforms it exposes the same info, because almost all platforms support IEEE 754 doubles now.